Next JS 14 - server component mid chain for library initializing
I am new to Next JS 14, and am trying to use a server component to initialize a library, while keeping the api keys hidden.
<client-component>
    <client-component>
        <client-component>
            <server-component>  //initialize library here w/api keys, and pass the variable down
                <client-component>  //use initialized variable to use library

I know you can have server components within client components with {children}, but I kind of need the reverse. I need the library to pass a variable down to the child from server to client components.
I tried making a server component with children, but it just makes it a client component.
